# enthought canopy does not start

Tags: python, python-2.7, enthought, canopy

I installed it about 3 weeks ago and it's been working fine, the 32 bit version onto my 64 bit PC. I tried opening it up today and nothing was working. It just wouldn't open, there was no loading error or message, nothing came up. I deleted it and downloaded the 64 bit version. Still the same. Then I deleted some PYTHONPATH I had because I heard that would make it work but still nothing.

Comment: Could you give some more context? OS version, other changes that occurred between 3 weeks ago and today?

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling is very unlikely to make a difference, so I don't recommend doing it; But if there has been corruption, as seems likely, then resetting (i.e. deleting the System, User, and configuration directories), then restarting Canopy, is likely to get you going again. See:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy

Comment: For the record, The current version of Canopy is 2.1.6. To update Canopy, please see ["Installing a new Canopy version"](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Installing-a-new-Canopy-version).